# parsing two different object's array from JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to parse JSON data .. i know how to do it for one object array .. but i don't know how to do it for a response which has to two arrays of different objects ..

for example this is the JSON:

```
  {
"shifts": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "region": "Eastren",
        "city": "Khobar",
        "nationality": "1",
        "id_service": 2,
        "shift_date": "2018-04-05",
        "shift_type": "night",
        "weekday": "sunday",
        "quantity_staff": 8,
        "lead_hours": 2,
        "created_at": "2018-04-23 11:46:20",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-24 08:46:14",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "region": "Eastren",
        "city": "Khobar",
        "nationality": "Phili",
        "id_service": 2,
        "shift_date": "2018-04-04",
        "shift_type": "night",
        "weekday": "sunday",
        "quantity_staff": 8,
        "lead_hours": 2,
        "created_at": "2018-04-23 11:47:25",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-23 12:53:05",
        "deleted_at": "2018-04-23"
    }
],
"prices": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "id_service": 2,
        "nationality": "Phili",
        "price": 150,
        "created_at": "2018-04-23 11:43:40",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-23 11:43:40",
        "deleted_at": null
    }
]
}
```

it has two array of objects .. shifts and prices .. how to parse each one of them?

my function:

```
 func GetShiftsAndPrices(id: Int){

    let todosEndpoint: String = "my link"
    guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
    todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    todosUrlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["id_service": id]
    let jsonTodo: Data
    do {
        jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
        todosUrlRequest.httpBody = jsonTodo
    } catch {
        print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
        return
    }

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: todosUrlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling POST on /public/api/login_customer")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }

        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        do {

             //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?

                print("Success!")

        } catch  {
            print("error parsing response from POST")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()}
   }
```

I have classes for both shift and price .. and know how to get each one if it was alone in a response .. like:

shifts:

```
                  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let shifts1 = try decoder.decode([Shifts].self, from: responseData)
                var shifts = [Shift]()
                for shift in shifts1{
                    let newshift = Shift(id: shift.id, region: shift.region, city: shift.city, nationality: shift.nationality, idService: shift.idService, shiftDate: shift.shiftDate, shiftType: shift.shiftType, weekday: shift.weekday, quantityStaff: shift.quantityStaff, leadHours: shift.leadHours)
                    shifts.append(newshift)
                }


                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: shifts)
                userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "shifts")
                userDefaults.synchronize()

                let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "shifts") as! Data
                let decodedShift = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Shift]

                for shift in decodedShift {
                    print(shift.id)
                }
```

prices:

```
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let prices1 = try decoder.decode([Prices].self, from: responseData)
        print("1")
        var prices = [Price]()
        for price in prices1{
            let newprice = Price(id: price.id, idService: price.idService,nationality: price.nationality, price: price.price)
            print("2")
            prices.append(newprice)
            print(newprice.nationality)
        }


        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: prices)
        userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "prices")
        userDefaults.synchronize()

        let decoded  = userDefaults.object(forKey: "prices") as! Data
        let decodedPrice = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Price]

        for price in decodedPrice {
            print(price.nationality)
        }
```

how to parse them both in one JSON response.. I'm new to this.. can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You can a container Object that has both shifts and prices as variables and make 2 maps and then each one of them will get mapped in it's own class

Comment: @ΒασίληςΔ. how to do this? sorry i'm new to this x_x

Comment: You don’t have two arrays; you have one dictionary. So that is a Decodable struct. And Shifts and Prices are Decodable structs. This is trivial with three Decodable structs. Do not use JSONSerialization at all.

Comment: @matt how to do it then? can you please tell me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an umbrella struct

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let shifts : [Shift]
    let prices : [Price]
}
```

and two different structs for shifts and prices:

```
struct Shift : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let region, city, nationality : String
    let idService : Int
    let shiftDate, shiftType, weekday : String
    let quantityStaff, leadHours : Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt : String
    let deletedAt : String?
}

struct Price : Decodable {
    let id, idService : Int
    let nationality : String
    let price : Int
    let createdAt, updatedAt : String
    let deletedAt : String?
}
```

---

To decode the JSON write

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try decoder .decode(Root.self, from: responseData)
    print(result.prices)
    print(result.shifts)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Further I recommend to decode keys like `shiftType` and `weekday` directly into an `enum` for example

```
enum ShiftType : String, Decodable {
    case day, night
}

struct Shift : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    ...
    let shiftType : ShiftType
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let shifts = responseJson.valueFor(key:"shifts") as? [String] ?? []
let prices = responseJson.valueFor(key:"prices") as? [String] ?? []
print("\(shifts) and \(prices)")
```

Comment: what is responseJson?

Comment: It is the response that you are getting after json parsing

Comment: This post has been flagged as low-quality.  @SuganyaMarlin please try to explain where the the OP was having trouble and how to resolve it, posting code only does not help the larger community who are looking for explanation